# How to use msdeploy to deploy an existing website on remote server

Tags: msdeploy

I already created a website "MyWebsite" on IIS on Windows server 2012, the physical path is `C:\builds\MyWebsite\wwwroot`, there are 1 other folders `approot` under directory `C:\builds\MyWebsite`, which is also necessary to make the website run. What I want to do is:

1. create a new folder `C:\builds\MyWebsiteNewBuild` in remote server which will be used to put my new build;
2. dump my new build `D:\Release\PublishOutput` from my local machine to the remote server, the publish output has 2 sub folders: `wwwroot` and `approot`;
3. change the physical path of "MyWebsite" to the new created folder `C:\builds\MyWebsiteNewBuild\wwwroot`, and restart the service.

I am new to the msdeploy, I searched and it seems that I can use

```
    msdeploy.exe -verb:dump-source:contentPath="D:\Release\PublishOutput" -dest:contentPath="C:\builds\MyWebsiteNewBuild",computerName="https://**.**.**.**/MsDeploy.axd",userName='administrator',password="*****",authType='Basic' -allowUntrusted
```

to dump my new build to remote server's destination folder, but the other requirements, such as change the physical path of my existing website, I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the website path using the appcmd through WebDeploy by using a manifest.

```
<runcommand path="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app /app.name:&quot;Default Web Site/app12&quot; /&#91;path='/'&#93;.physicalPath:C:\temp\app12" waitInterval="5000"/>
```

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/28/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-change-iis-siteapp-physical-path-with-msdeploy/

The following post describes how to create a custom WebDeploy package based on a manifest:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/23/deploy-an-asp-net-website-not-web-application-with-msdeploy/

Comment: Thanks Chief7, with your suggest, I think the operation "-prosync" could solve my problem, I first run command "appcmd set vdir "MySite/" -physicalPath:"C:\builds\MyWebsiteNewBuild\wwwroot"" locally on the AWS EC2 instance, which successfully changed the physical path of the web site "MySite", so next step for me would be conjunct this command with "-postsync" operation, I will update here later once I get it working .